# Bolt.cm login as Guest Editor causes endless redirect

Tags: bolt-cms

With Bolt.cm I created a user with Guest Editor access (the default settings for permissions roles). When I log in as that user the browser says there is an endless redirect. It appears to be trying to access the dashboard but I'd like it to go to the home page for now albeit with a logged in status. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. What version of Bolt are you running?

Comment: The toolbar when viewing the dashboard suggests it's Bolt 2.0.0.

Comment: Ah, OK.  The master branch that you are on is pre-beta for 2.0...  Should be mostly stable, but things such as this might break.

Can you open an issue on GitHub?